# How to get my original ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I created a User Control that has ViewModelA() as its ViewModel then inside my View, there's a StackPanel that uses ViewModelA.Data as DataContext.

My problem is inside this StackPanel, I have a button that needs to implement my created ICommand inside ViewModelA(). How can I do that?

Is there anything like `<Button DataContext="DataContext.Parent" />` or something like that?

Here's how I implemented my ViewModel and View:

App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelA}">
    <vw:ViewA />
</DataTemplate>
```

ViewA.xaml (where the button inside the stack panel should implement the ICommand)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RightPaneDetails"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="15,0,0,30"
            DataContext="{Binding Data}">
    <!-- Some controls goes here that binds to ViewModelA.Data properties -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button DataContext={Binding} Command="{Binding LookupCommand}" /> <!-- This button should implement the ViewModelA.LookupCommand -->
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

TIA

PS, ViewModelA.Data is my model.

Comment: DataContext is inherited down the visual tree, there is no need to specify DataContext at all. Remove all DataContext in ViewA, all controls should default their DataContext back to ViewModelA.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But my controls (textboxes and labels) are bounded from ViewModelA.Data's properties... Would it be ugly if I remove `<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Data}"> ...... </StackPanel>` then put to all of my binding controls as `<TextBox Text="{Binding Data.LastName}" />`

Comment: Try AnjumSKhan's answer without the DataContext part.

Comment: @Jai - I did try it but still not working. Button is still looking at Data and not ViewModelA...

Comment: @Jai - No wait... It worked!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set `DataContext` as `ViewModelA` in your UC. So, you can use

`<Button DataContext={Binding} Command="{Binding DataContext.LookupCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />`

It can also be written as :

`<Button DataContext={Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor} } Command="{Binding LookupCommand}" />`

Comment: I made assumption regarding your UserControl's DataContext. Show your full XAML.

Comment: Have a deeper look at the controls' DataContext by either using Snoop or Live-Property-Explorer (VS2015)

Comment: @AnjumSKhan - there's nothing really special going on. Just that the "Data" is my Model inside my ViewModelA. When I try to place my button outside the StackPanel, LookupCommand works.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan - After few tries, it works. I dunno why but I was sure I restarted VS then Jai (from comments under question) mentoined to try yours and I tried your answer again without `DataContext="{Binding}"` and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @JackFrost Seriously, I thought the DataContext part wouldn't have any effect, because the binding engine would not bother with DataContext at all when we use RelativeSource, not sure what happened here. Maybe AnjumSKhan can explain why; he's very knowledgeable here.

Comment: `Mode=FindAncestor` is redundant. Remove it from the binding on order to make xaml more readable

Comment: @Jai Using RelativeSource we will get our DataSource, then we need to specify which property of that DataSource we are interested in. We want DataContext of UC which will give us ViewModelA.

Comment: @Liero I always use `Mode` for clarity.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan What I mean is, `DataContext="{Binding}"` should have absolutely no effect on `Command`'s binding, because for the command binding we have already used RelativeSource. I am just not too sure why this solution didn't work until that `DataContext="{Binding}"` part is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Although @AnjumSKhan's solution is correct, I would like to propose alternative solution:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RightPaneDetails"> <!-- do not set bind datacontext here -->

    <!-- Some controls goes here that binds to ViewModelA.Data properties, e.g: -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.SomeProperty}" />
    <!-- If there too many elements bound to Data, you can group them in stackpanel -->


    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- This button is databound to ViewModelA.LookupCommand 
             DataContext doesn't have to be set, since it's inherited from parent. Actually entire stackpanel is redundant here-->
        <Button Command="{Binding LookupCommand}" /> 
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see I just avoided setting DataContext on the parent RightPaneDetails so the children can easily access both ViewModelA.Data's properties (TextBlock) and ViewModelA's properties (Button)

---

Few other notes:

1. Notice, that instead of

   ```
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}
   ```

   you can write just

   ```
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}
   ```
2. Alternative solution to RelativeSource is ElementName:

   ```
   <StackPanel x:Name="Root">
     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Data}">
       <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.LookupCommand, ElementName=Root}" />
   ```

   I preffer this because existence of "Root" element is checked at compile time and it is more readable.
3. Avoid binding DataContext and another Property on the same element, e.g:

   ```
   <Button DataContext="{Binding....}" Command="{Binding ...}" />
   ```

   There is no guarantee, which binding will be evaluated first. You can, however, set IsAsyc=True to the second binding `Command={Binding ..., IsAsync=True}` to ensure it will be evaluated later than non async bindings

Comment: I was also thinking of this as well. But apparently OP finds this ugly. For my own personal preference, I would choose this method as well. Binding becomes more complicated when you start to assign DataContext at different parts. I would prefer to have the whole View to use the inherited DataContext, and make more effect in writing chained binding paths.